# having trouble in order by with union

Tags: mysql, union

I need to get information about cliien invetation for the year 2019 and the year 2020.
but only orders below 1000$ .

i was trying to make 2 tables and getting union.
one is getting for 2019 and the other for thw year 2020

every one of them is working precfet by I cant make then Union and not to order by client

here is the code (Mysql)

```
use northwind;
select * from 
 #    1000$  table for 2019
(select C.CustomerID,C.ContactName,                         
D.ProductID,D.OrderID,round(sum(Quantity*UnitPrice*(1-Discount)),2) as 
total_in_order
from   orders O  join orderdetails D on O.OrderID=D.OrderID  join customers C on                 
C.CustomerID=O.CustomerID
where year(o.orderdate) =2019
 group by OrderID, C.CustomerID
 having Total_in_order<1000
 order by C.CustomerID
 ) 
 union
 select * from 
 #    1000$  table for 2020
 (
 select C.CustomerID,C.ContactName,         
 D.ProductID,D.OrderID,round(sum(Quantity*UnitPrice*(1-Discount)),2) as 
 total_in_order
 from   orders O  join orderdetails D on O.OrderID=D.OrderID  join customers C on                 
 C.CustomerID=O.CustomerID
where year(o.orderdate) =2020
 group by OrderID, C.CustomerID
 having Total_in_order<1000
  order by C.CustomerID
  )
```

Comment: Can I suggest you run the query through an automatic formatter? For example: https://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm

Answer (score 1):

As the error message clearly explains it. If you use

```
SELECT ...FROM (SELECT ...)
```

The FROM Clause needs an object name, so you can do something like this

```
use northwind;
select * from 
 #    1000$  table for 2019
(select C.CustomerID,C.ContactName,                         
D.ProductID,D.OrderID,round(sum(Quantity*UnitPrice*(1-Discount)),2) as 
total_in_order
from   orders O  join orderdetails D on O.OrderID=D.OrderID  join customers C on                 
C.CustomerID=O.CustomerID
where year(o.orderdate) =2019
 group by OrderID, C.CustomerID
 having Total_in_order<1000
 order by C.CustomerID
 ) t2
 union
 select * from 
 #    1000$  table for 2020
 (
 select C.CustomerID,C.ContactName,         
 D.ProductID,D.OrderID,round(sum(Quantity*UnitPrice*(1-Discount)),2) as 
 total_in_order
 from   orders O  join orderdetails D on O.OrderID=D.OrderID  join customers C on                 
 C.CustomerID=O.CustomerID
where year(o.orderdate) =2020
 group by OrderID, C.CustomerID
 having Total_in_order<1000
  order by C.CustomerID
  ) t1
```

but when you remove the `SELECR *`

You can use

```
use northwind;
#select * from 
 #    1000$  table for 2019
(select C.CustomerID,C.ContactName,                         
D.ProductID,D.OrderID,round(sum(Quantity*UnitPrice*(1-Discount)),2) as 
total_in_order
from   orders O  join orderdetails D on O.OrderID=D.OrderID  join customers C on                 
C.CustomerID=O.CustomerID
where year(o.orderdate) =2019
 group by OrderID, C.CustomerID
 having Total_in_order<1000
 order by C.CustomerID
 ) 
 union
#select * from 
 #    1000$  table for 2020
 (
 select C.CustomerID,C.ContactName,         
 D.ProductID,D.OrderID,round(sum(Quantity*UnitPrice*(1-Discount)),2) as 
 total_in_order
 from   orders O  join orderdetails D on O.OrderID=D.OrderID  join customers C on                 
 C.CustomerID=O.CustomerID
where year(o.orderdate) =2020
 group by OrderID, C.CustomerID
 having Total_in_order<1000
  order by C.CustomerID
  )
```